# Dispatch `:=` on second argument

Tags: r, operator-overloading, r-s4

I would like to implement a function `:=(lhs, rhs)`, that accepts *any* expression for `lhs`, while `rhs` has to be of class `X`.

In order to avoid conflicts with other packages (e.g. `data.table`), a generic function `:=` should be set up via `setGeneric(":=")` that dispatches based on the class of the second argument.

However,

```
setMethod(
  ":="
  , c("ANY", "X")
  , function(lhs, rhs) NULL
)
```

assumes the first argument to be an actual object, i.e. `bla := x` results in

> Error in `:=`(bla, x) : object 'bla' not found

whenever `bla` is not bound.

Is there a way to define such a function while not influencing the behaviour of other implementations of the same name, whenever the second argument is of class `X`?

*Remark:* `:=` cannot be defined as an appropriate S3 generic since it is dispatched on `lhs`, instead of `rhs`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to say `signature("ANY","X")` instead of a vector

```
setGeneric(":=", function(lhs,rhs) standardGeneric(":="))
setMethod(":=", signature("ANY","ANY"), function(lhs,rhs){print("Default")})
setMethod(":=", signature("ANY","foo"), function(lhs,rhs){print("foo Method")})

bla <- 1:10
bar <- 1:10
class(bar) <- "foo"

bla:=bla
#Default
bla:=bar
#foo Method
```

Comment: Guess you mean `signature` instead of `structure`. This does not solve the problem: If `bla` is not defined, `bla := bar` results in an error.

Comment: Yes, the top part I meant `signature`. The code block I presented should be reproducible. See [S4](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/S4.html) guide for more info

Comment: If you are trying to call a function in which the lhs argument is just not defined in any environment, then I think the error is unavoidable. It seems like you want some sort of lazy evaluation - e.i. the symbol is only accessed when it is evaluated in some way. I'm not sure if this functionality exists with S4 since the class signature of both is accessed in order to decide on a dispatch.

Comment: This would be exactly what I am looking for and I am afraid, too, that S4 does not allow this. The aim would be to use `substitute(lhs)` in the function body, `lhs` needs to be unevaluated for that purpose. Any other idea, how to define `:=` without screwing  implementations from other packages (or vice versa)? Or is there a binary operator that evaluates the rhs first?

Comment: 'All arguments in the signature of the generic function will be evaluated when the function is called, rather than using lazy evaluation. Therefore, it's important to exclude from the signature any arguments that need to be dealt with symbolically (such as the expr argument to function with). Note that only actual arguments are evaluated, not default expressions. A missing argument enters into the method selection as class "missing".' - [source](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/methods/html/Methods_Details.html)

Comment: I cant think of any way around this mate. You may just need to make a new function like `%:=%`. You could call `exists(deparse(substitute(lhs)))` to indicate if the value is found anywhere then change your code flow from that. Any use of `useMethod` or `setMethod` will evaluate the first argument (at least) and result in the same error.

Comment: As a side note: `%:=%` has a different operator precedence than `:=`.

Comment: You are right that `lhs` cannot be in the signature as that would cause it to be evaluated. Your best bet is to write a method that examines `lhs` manually using `deparse` or whatever (without it being in the signature), and uses `callNextMethod` or similar if `lhs` is not the sort of thing it was looking for (so other packages should still work, albeit with a small overhead). Don't have the time to turn this into a full answer right now...